# Add custom Asset Library path on startup

Tags: python, path, asset, library, api

I run a small studio and we are looking into centralizing blender install.

OCIO and addons I can deal with a custom startup.py script that I launch when blender is started, but I cant find a way to add a custom asset library path, or font path or any of those paths, usually in other apps those would just be environment variables.

Is there a way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Hello. Not sure if it'll help but asset library paths are stored in `bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.asset_libraries` https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UserAssetLibrary.html